# Generating paths in submodule context given path in parent module context

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I am creating an [attribute macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#attribute-macros) that can be invoked with (a path to) some type amongst its attributes:

```rust
#[my_macro(path::to::SomeType)]
```

This macro generates a module, within which the specified type is to be used:

```rust
mod generated {
    use path::to::SomeType;
}
```

However, from within that generated module, the path as provided may no longer be correct:

- if the path is prefixed with `::`, it remains correct—I can determine this within the proc macro;
- otherwise, if the path starts with an identifier that is in a prelude (such as that of an external crate), it remains correct—I can't see any way to determine this within the proc macro;
- otherwise it must now be prefixed with `super::` for resolution to succeed.

Of course, I could require users of the macro to provide a path that will be correct from within the generated module, but that would not be very ergonomic.

Instead, I'm currently generating a type alias within the parent module:

```rust
type __generated_SomeType = path::to::SomeType;
mod generated {
    use super::__generated_SomeType as SomeType;
}
```

However this is not only a tad clunky, but it furthermore pollutes the parent namespace.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried `use super::*;` at the top of the generated module?

Comment: @PitaJ: Yes, sorry should have mentioned that... I discounted it because it could cause name collisions within the generated module (avoidance of which is the reason that a generated module is being used in the first place).

Comment: A type alias isn't really appropriate here (for example, it doesn't allow generics). Better to use `use path::to::SomeType as __generated_SomeType;`.

Comment: I think your best bet is `#[doc(hidden)] use path::to::SomeType as __generated_SomeType;` unless you want to require that all external paths are prefixed with `::` and put `super::` in front of everything else.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a satisfying solution. But there's an alternative, and a way to improve your current approach.

The alternative is to use a `const` item:

```rust
const _: () = {
    // ... your generated code here
};
```

It can still cause name collisions with items from the parent scope, but at least the generated items aren't visible outside of the `const`. This is what most macro authors do.

If you don't want to do that, you can go with your current approach, but you should add `#[doc(hidden)]` to the `__generated_SomeType` type, so it doesn't show up in documentation. Also, you should use an import instead of a type alias to support generic types, as suggested by @ChayimFriedman:

```rust
#[doc(hidden)]
use path::to::SomeType as __generated_SomeType;
```

I was just about to suggest combining these to approaches by putting a module inside a `const` item, but it doesn't work:

```rust
const _: () = {
    use path::to::SomeType as __generated_SomeType;

    mod generated {
        // doesn't work :(
        use super::__generated_SomeType as SomeType;
    }
};
```

Rust complains that `__generated_SomeType` doesn't exist in the parent module.

Comment: "Rust complains `that __generated_SomeType` doesn't exist in the parent module." because that's the entire point of `const _: () = { ... };`, to not pollute the namespace.

Comment: I assumed that, since the module is within the `const` item, it can access other items within the same `const` item, but that's apparently not the case. This could actually be considered a bug. It is entirely reasonable to expect that `use super::...` can access items in the scope where the module is defined. I'm _not_ asking that items in the `const` item should be visible outside of it.

Comment: But from Rust POV, `const` is not like a module and does not participate in the module hierarchy. It is a way to isolate names, but the parent of `generated` is the module, not the `const`.

Comment: The generated module itself needs to be exposed, so a `const` item here is not of any use (and, as you mention, does not in any case address the issue at hand).  Thanks for the suggestion, though!